# Java: Singleton using ENUM.. Is my object singleton and threadsafe

Tags: java, enums, singleton

I'm trying to understand creating a Singleton Object using Enum.
I wrote this code. Is this threadsafe?. Please tell me if not ,how to make this

```
 public enum MySingleton {

    INSTANCE;
    private static final Employee emp = Employee.getInstance();
    }


public class Employee {
    private static Employee emp;

    public static Employee getInstance(){
    emp=new Employee();
    return emp;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto,yes I did.still have confusion regarding how to make `Employee` singleton using Enum

Comment: you want to implement the singleton pattern for  Employee or MySingleton?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto,for Employee

Comment: so the code that you are looking for is public enum Employee { INSTANCE }

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, It means I'm not taking `Employee` as a class , but as ENUM

Comment: yes that's right you don't need a class and an enum only an enum

Comment: Thank you.. Now I understood

Answer (score 0):

It's not thread safe because `Employee.getInstance()` could be called by multiple threads and return one or more objects.

A simple solution is to make `Employee` an `interface`

```
public enum MySingleton implements Employee {
    INSTANCE;
}

public interface Employee {

}
```

This is thread safe as the construction of INSTANCE is thread safe.

Comment: Now How will i get `Employee` object

Comment: @AnilKumar with MySingleton.INSTANCE in this case